# change direction of segue of pushViewController in iPhone

Tags: iphone, pushviewcontroller

I am using the following code to launch a view controller named secondViewController.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
```

The code successfully causes the secondVC to slide in from the right to left

After the user is done I would like the user to be able to go back to the first View Controller.   For this purpose I have wired a back button to a method that uses similar code, however in this case I would like it to slide from left to right, i.e. the opposite direction.  However, not surprisingly the return VC also goes from right to left.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:returnViewController animated:YES];
```

Is there a way to reverse the direction so that in the second case, it slides from left to right?

**EDIT:**

Using the code from the answer suggested by Brendan, I have added the following method to override the pushViewController.    I am calling it the same way but have had to comment the swapButtonsForViewController as the selector SwapButtons is not recognized.  Not sure what it really does.

In addition, if you call it as super, I get an error: no visible@interface in the super VC for this VC.  Not sure how to fix that.  If I change super to self, error disappears but it still goes right to left.

```
- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated{
    UIView *theWindow = self.view ;
    if( animated ) {
        CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
        [animation setDuration:0.45f];
        [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
        [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
        [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut]];
        [[theWindow layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@""];
    }

    //make sure we pass the super "animated:NO" or we will get both our
    //animation and the super's animation
    [super pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];

 //       [self swapButtonsForViewController:viewController];


}
```

Comment: there's a similar question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26465732/ios-7-change-pushviewcontroller-animation-direction Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Oops, a few things in addition to my comment:

Did you inherit from `UINavigationController`? That will help, if you didn't do that already.

Also, the link I shared with you will replace the direction for both cases, unfortunately. I should have read the question more carefully, apologies.

Good news though! Try both of these:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16535931/5806860

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16384808/5806860

Those are similar solutions, but have minor changes that could potentially solve your problem.